# Passing parameters to template files in asciidoc

Tags: asciidoc

I'm generating asciidoc snippets using spring rest docs.

I can include the generated snippets in my doc page. However, I want to define the structure of each secion once in a seperate adoc file, and have a single line for each of those in my index file.

Currently my *index.adoc* file looks like this:

```
= My Http Api Docs

= GET /units/:id

== Path Parameters
include::{snippets}/units/get/path-parameters.adoc[]

== Response Fields
include::{snippets}/units/get/response-fields.adoc[]
```

I want it to be like this instead

*index.adoc*

```
= My Http Api Docs

usemytemplates::mytemplate.adoc[method='get', url='units', desc='/units/:id']
```

*mytemplate.adoc*

```
= {method} {desc}

== Path Parameters
include::{snippets}/{url}/{method}/path-parameters.adoc[]

== Response Fields
include::{snippets}/{url}/{method}/response-fields.adoc[]
```

Anyone know how something like this can be done?

Answer (score 11):

I was able to solve this by using the substitution syntax before each include statement.

My index.adoc file looks like this and it works:

```
:method: get
:url: units
:desc: /utils/:id
include::mytemplate.adoc[]

:method: get
:url: members
:desc: /members/:id
include::mytemplate.adoc[]
```

Comment: Here is an example in the off. doc: https://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#include-multiple